# Jmeter thread is rising very slowly

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter script where in I initiate the test with concurrent 300 users(threads), then with every 10sec, 100 more threads are added. My script was running absolutely fine. But suddenly I am noticing that inspite of adding 100 threads, its adding 3 or 4 threads.

I have increased swap memory, still no go.
[image]

[image]

I am using 4GB machine, in which i have made "Xms=1g Xms=3GB"

And this is how slowly threads are getting added:

Comment: are the threads configured to run indefinitely or to die after they get the first response?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how "absolutely fine" execution of your scenario should look like:

[image]

Given you have that many threads in the `Finished` state there is something preventing them from doing their normal job so instead of finishing execution of all [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) of the current iteration and starting the new one the threads are being terminated somewhere in between and JMeter restarts them.

Your question doesn't contain sufficient information in order to guess the reason, inspect your test plan and make sure you have enough test data, in case of [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) ensure that `Stop Thread on EOF` is set to **False**, etc.

If your test plan looks okayish check [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for any suspicious entries

Comment: Thanks for replying Dmitri T. So I am running a jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group > followed by bzm - Parallel Controller. In the controller I am hitting 9 apis. So one thread enters "bzm - Parallel Controller." and hits 9 apis. But what I am not able to understand is why there are huge number in started and finished. Wherein these numbers were coming when my script was running fine aswell. CSV file already has those settings in place.